# Filter files based on extensions using gedit

Tags: file, filter, gedit

Is there a way to include or exclude certain files from being shown in gedit ?

For example, in my project directory, there are .metadata files.
How can I filter them?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in the side panel filter box and hit enter

`*.metadata`